# When I hit the set command in the osx terminal where does the output come from?

Tags: terminal

I get a load of stuff when I type the word

```
set
```

in mac osx 10.8 terminal.

I only recognise a tiny bit of it is in my .profile and .bashrc files. I have looked also in /etc/paths

I cannot find where the output comes from. I have been searching about for a good while now and nothing extra has come up. Where is this command pulling the information output on the terminal from exactly?

e.g. this function  `update_terminal_cwd ()`

Comment: Different things come from different places. We don't know what "stuff" you're asking about.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz added example.

Comment: Check `/etc/bashrc`.

Comment: I had done that firstly @DavidSchwartz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set` is showing you all environmental variables and builtin functions that exist on your machine and in your shell among other information gathered.

If you want to know the full story, [check the source code for the builtin.](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/bash/bash-86.1/bash-3.2/builtins/set.c)

To address your example, `update_terminal_cwd` is in the default systemwide .bashrc file:

```
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
   return
fi

PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
# Make bash check its window size after a process completes
shopt -s checkwinsize
# Tell the terminal about the working directory at each prompt.
if [ "$TERM_PROGRAM" == "Apple_Terminal" ] && [ -z "$INSIDE_EMACS" ]; then
    update_terminal_cwd() {
        # Identify the directory using a "file:" scheme URL,
        # including the host name to disambiguate local vs.
        # remote connections. Percent-escape spaces.
    local SEARCH=' '
    local REPLACE='%20'
    local PWD_URL="file://$HOSTNAME${PWD//$SEARCH/$REPLACE}"
    printf '\e]7;%s\a' "$PWD_URL"
    }
    PROMPT_COMMAND="update_terminal_cwd; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you. Although there's still work to do I think you answered as completely you could given the situation. Aside from that I have been trying to find the place where my PS1 is set for ages and finally I can get rid of the annoying PS1='\h:\W \u\$ 'and replace it with PS1='> ' thanks to you +1